# Procedure to use Mojento rest api in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, magento

I am working on the Majento2 web api and I have no knowledge regarding use of the magenta web api, so please help me regarding how to implement post and get magenta web services in iOS project. i like to handle this form of data:-

```
{
"items": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "sku": "521609",
  "name": "BUDWEISER 36 CAN ",
  "attribute_set_id": 4,
  "price": 72.5,
  "status": 1,
  "visibility": 4,
  "type_id": "simple",
  "created_at": "2018-11-17 18:36:26",
  "updated_at": "2018-11-18 16:01:45",
  "product_links": [],
  "tier_prices": [],
  "custom_attributes": [
   {
   "attribute_code": "meta_title",
   "value": "BUDWEISER 36 CAN "
   },
```

Comment: I've just started developing an open-source app, it could be useful for people going to work on Magento app https://github.com/troublediehard/swift-magento-app